# Visual Studio 2017 loses intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Why does Visual Studio 2017 lose its intellisense, or the suggestions it makes while typing, in this scenario:

I have a class called `ReformattedProvider` in my code. I type 'Reformate d' (note the spelling error with space in between), and realize that there is error. so I deleted 'd', the empty space and then 'e'. By the time I reach 't', I notice that the suggestions/intellisense are no more there.

Why is this and how can I get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: Typing the space forced the IntelliSense popup to close.  Press Ctrl+Space to bring it back.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default settings, like Hans Passant's suggestion, it would work well if you use keyboard.

Ctrl + Space or Ctrl + J

Or you can go to Tools-> Options-> Environment-> Keyboard and check what is assigned to these shortcuts.